# parsing parameters to main function

Tags: c++, parsing

I don't understand the following piece of code:

```
int  main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// See if we've been given a seed to use (for testing purposes).  When you
// specify a random seed, the evolution will be exactly the same each time
// you use that seed number.

  unsigned int seed = 0;
  for(int ii=1; ii<argc; ii++) {
    if(strcmp(argv[ii++],"seed") == 0) {
      seed = atoi(argv[ii]);
    }
  }
```

How can I pass a value to main function? I read a bit and found out that it is called parsing, could you please clarify what is it?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add what platform you're on? Maybe even add the requisite tags?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters `int argc` and `char** argv` are automatically passed to `main` and are parsed from the command line used to invoke the program.  They are, respective, the number of command line parameters including the program name itself and an array of pointers to C-style strings of these parameters. So if the following is used to invoke `my_prog`:

```
./my_prog file 10
```

`main` gets called with `argc` set  to 3 and `argv` is a `char*` array of 3 pointers to `"./my_prog"`, `"file"` and `"10"`

EDIT: thanks to @BasileStarynkevitch for pointing out on POSIX complaint systems `argv` will have an `argc + 1` element of `NULL` to also indicate end of parameters.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify what I understood from you, the loop is for checking if an input "seed" was given and the value corresponding to it, right?

Comment: Going by the code posted, the code is looking for something like `./my_prog seed 10` (check out the docs for the ++ prefix and postfix operators, they're a bit tricky to understand). Oh, and BTW -- if this is just test code, that's fine, otherwise this is kinda bad code for various reasons.

Comment: @uliwitness thanks, my bad. Peer - yes the loop is finding `"seed"` and setting the `seed` variable to the integer value of the next parameter string.

Comment: Actually, (in your example) `argv`  has even a fourth element, which is certain to be `NULL` (at least on POSIX systems)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch good point. Edited answer accordingly